# draw rotated path at particular point

Tags: android

I'm working on a custom view (`extends View`) and working in the `onDraw` method.

I have made a path of an arrow:

```
    ARROW_PATH = new Path();
    ARROW_PATH.setLastPoint(20, 37);
    ARROW_PATH.lineTo(14, 25);
    ARROW_PATH.lineTo(18, 26);
    ARROW_PATH.lineTo(17, 4);
    ARROW_PATH.lineTo(23, 4);
    ARROW_PATH.lineTo(22, 26);
    ARROW_PATH.lineTo(26, 25);
    ARROW_PATH.close();
```

In different scenarios it needs to be rotated to depict a certain angle, and I need to draw it at a particular coordinate in the view. The coordinate also changes depending on the scenario.

I've tried playing around with `Canvas.rotate` however, it looks like the aspect of the path is skewed when the `px` and `py` values are not equal (the arrow gets narrower and taller when `py > px`.

I have also tried `Canvas.rotate(angle, 0, 0);` and then `ARROW_PATH.moveTo(x, y);` but it looks like the coords are rotated by the arbitrary angle making it very hard to calculate the required coordinate.

Ideally, I'd like to rotate the path and not the canvas but I don't think this operation is supported by the API.

Can someone suggest a better approach to this problem?

thanks, p.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a way of making it work.

Firstly I modified my `Path` so that it was centered

```
ARROW_PATH = new Path();
ARROW_PATH.setLastPoint(0, 17);
ARROW_PATH.lineTo(-6, 5);
ARROW_PATH.lineTo(-2, 6);
ARROW_PATH.lineTo(-3, -16);
ARROW_PATH.lineTo(3, -16);
ARROW_PATH.lineTo(2, 6);
ARROW_PATH.lineTo(6, 5);
ARROW_PATH.close();
```

and then an extra call to translate helps locate the drawing:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle, x, y);
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(x, y);
canvas.drawPath(ARROW_PATH, paint);
canvas.restore();
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Why do you save the state twice? Looks redundant.

Comment: test it without doing the double save/double restore... it doesn't work. if you have a better solution (that you have tested), post it.

Answer (score 34):

This is a proper way to permanently rotate a path (it will stay like this until the next application of a matrix):

```
Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
RectF bounds = new RectF();
mPath.computeBounds(bounds, true);
mMatrix.postRotate(myAngle, bounds.centerX(), bounds.centerY());
mPath.transform(mMatrix);
```

Comment: It helps, the way question asks to rotate a Path instance on android canvas around its center.

Comment: Thnaks man saved my day! i can't use _canvas.rotate(mRotation, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);_ because I'm using LayerDrawable

Comment: the best solution

Comment: this is actually the answer, as canvas rotate will not rotate the path and if you want to use the path width or height later , after applying rotation on canvas will give you wrong result so better apply this approach. but im bit confuse that how could i achieve smooth rotation with matrix?